# Check if column contains missing values

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm writing a validation function which should check that:

1. A `Dataset<Row> ds` has the columns `col1` and `col2`. It may contain other columns as well.
2. Verify that there are no missing values (NaN, NULL, null, etc.) in `col1` and `col2`.

The code should be a Java code. Here is what I have so far

```java
private static boolean isSleepDataValid(SparkSession spark, Dataset<Row> ds) {

    ds.createOrReplaceTempView("validityData");
    if (spark.sql("SELECT col1 FROM validityData WHERE col1 IS NULL").count() > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (spark.sql("SELECT col2 FROM validityData WHERE col2 IS NULL").count() > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, this is ugly and I'm looking for a nicer and cleaner way. I would like to avoid `SparkSession spark` in the signature and SQL in the function's body.

Comment: Maybe this can help (although in python): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55964196/check-whether-dataframe-contains-any-null-values/55964733#55964733

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the Spark DSL, something like

```
return ds
  .filter(ds.col("col1").isNull().or(ds.col("col2").isNull()))
  .limit(1)
  .count() == 0;
```

Note that `limit 1` may increase efficiency when null values are found.

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
private static boolean isSleepDataValid(SparkSession spark, Dataset<Row> ds) {
     return (ds.count() == ds.na().drop().count()) 
}
```

`ds.count()` returns total number of rows.
`df.na().drop()` will drop rows containing **null** values. If there are no null values the count of rows will be equal and the method will return true otherwise false.